# Fix for 2018 MBP internal speaker noise bursts?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, speakers

I have an issue with my 2018 15" MacBook Pro where the internal speakers will start to emit loud periodic bursts of noise after I've been using them for a seemingly random amount of time.

If I use an external audio interface, there is no problem. If I plug in headphones, there is no problem. If I enter `sudo pkill coreaudiod` in the terminal (or reboot), the problem goes away (because Core Audio restarts) but eventually comes back.

Apparently this is a known issue with 2018 MBPs, but I haven't found anything about a permanent fix online. I'm running full-updated High Sierra on it. Is there a fix available that I just haven't found in my searches? Can it be fixed with a replacement under Apple Care?

Comment: If it's still under AppleCare, I would take it in.  Just don't kill the process prior to going in and if at all possible video it and provide it to the techs.

Comment: @Allan That's what I've been thinking. The only thing is I've read that's it's all 2018 MBPs that have the problem and a replacement won't fix it, but maybe that's incorrect. That's why I'm surprised there isn't a software patch or firmware update from Apple for it, but if there is a hardware fix that would explain the absence of a patch.

Comment: I would take it in to AppleCare for the simple reason you paid a premium for that laptop (but that's me...the more I pay for something, the more I will become "that guy" when there's an issue).  That said, I've experienced audio issues in one form or another and resolved every one of them with a quality [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286015/119271).

Comment: @Allan I have two USB interfaces and a Thunderbolt 2 interface, so when I'm really working it's not a huge problem. It's a problem when I just want to sit on the couch and compose and then walk to the kitchen and the bedroom. The new MBP speakers sound much better than the old so it would be nice to be able to use them for working anywhere when having better sound quality isn't important. I just thought I'd check here to see if there was something self service I missed. Getting an AppleCare appointment and getting to the Apple Store can be a pain. IMHO Behringer is not "quality" ;-)