# How do I stream audio from a Computer's Browser to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, google-chrome, streaming

I have to do this because I don't have a working sound card in my Macbook and the system can not play audio. I therefore need to get the sound input directly form the browser (Chrome Extension) and stream it to another device (iPhone app). If this exists that would be awesome, otherwise I might write it myself.

Comment: To stream audio, you something that that will act as a “server” then broadcast the audio via multicast.  If it’s coming from your browser, you’ll need something that will “grab” that audio.  Don’t over complicate this; get a [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286015/119271) instead and thisnwill not just solve your issue but get you better sound