# No sound output from Macbook to TV via HDMI?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, usb, hdmi, television

I’ve got an LG OLED TV with HDMI support. I have a 2018 Macbook with USB-C ports running Catalina 10.15.4.

I bought a USB-C to HDMI 2.0 cable and hooked up my Macbook to my TV.

The pictures come out perfectly, but the sound continues to output through my Macbook.

I have verified that the TV is selected as the output under System Peferences -> Sound -> Output.

[image]

Comment: If you select an alternate audio device, it can’t be playing though the MacBook speakers.  What HDMI Spec is that cable?  You need a minimum of 1.4, ideally 2.1

Comment: It is 2.x. After playing with it, it seems if I connect it before the TV is on it doesn't work, but if I connect it after the TV is on then it works. Probably a bug. Still frustrating and wish it was consistently working.

Comment: If HDMI wasn't so ubiquitous in consumer devices, I would avoid it like the plague (it's flaky as hell).  Personally, I use a [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286015/119271) for any external audio.  I've found it much, much more reliable